# Excel - How to convert UTC date time

Tags: excel

I would like to use this string as a date time in excel

```
2016-04-06T18:05:32.6550717+03:00
```

How can it be converted?

Comment: is the string always from the same timezone? ie+03:00 or will you get some from other timezones such as -05:00 as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two things in the date/time that are giving issue.  The first is the `T` that denotes the start of time.  Excel uses a space.  The second is the Everything to the right of the `+`.

If we get rid of those then excel will see it as a Date/Time.  So use this to remove the unwanted information:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(G2,FIND("+",G2)-1),"T"," ")
```

[image]

**EDIT**

As was pointed out by @ForwardEd this only brings in the UTC time.

Upon further thinking since this is computer generated the format will remain the same.  The following formula also considers the time zone:

```
=(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,27),"T"," "))+(MID(A1,28,3)/24)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Then format it like you want:

[image]

And you get:

[image]

---

Comment: and if you need the 3 hour time shift adjustment for some use, you can store the string (including the + or - for the shift) in column C with `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-IFERROR(FIND("+",A1)-1,FIND("-",A1,9)-1))`

Comment: @ForwardEd good call.  I was waiting for further guidance from the OP before editing post.  But, on further thinking since this is UTC the format will stay the same so I simply did; `=(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,27),"T"," "))+(MID(A1,28,3)/24)`  Which will take that into account also.

Comment: If you happen to be dealing with other timezones that are in the - direction, Scott's formula will need to be adjusted to `=--SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(G2,FIND("-",G2,9)-1),"T"," ")` or you can change it to one that will deal with both directions `=--SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(G2,IFERROR(FIND("+",G2),FIND("-",G2,9))-1),"T"," ")`

Comment: or do what scott said since his comment came up while I was still commenting and I did not see it!

Comment: For someone looking for this in ```Excel 2016``` you have to use ```;``` instead of ```,``` meaning: ```=(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1;27);"T";" "))+(MID(A1;28;3)/24)```

Comment: @G.Siganos it does not have to do with the version of excel but your local settings.  If your local settings are in the US then ones uses `,` no matter the version.

Answer (score 9):

Given a UTC dateTime e.g. : `2017-08-22T14:26:30.000+1000`

```
=(DATEVALUE(MID(A1,1,10)) +TIMEVALUE( MID(A1,12,12)))+TIME(MID(A1,25,4)/100,0,0)
```

Comment: Or if you don't care about the time and have something like this: 
`2017-12-18T23:41:29.584Z` do:

`=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,1,10))`

Comment: @JamieD : Time is important, losing information is not an option

Answer (score 0):

This worked to convert
from :Brisbane time -  2022-04-24T11:04:33+10:00
to   :UTC time      -  2022-04-24 01:04:33
=TEXT((LEFT(A1,10)&" "&MID(A1,12,8))-10/24,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")