# how to change a date and timestamp from UTC to any local time using Excel

Tags: excel, datetime

I am desperately trying to change a Date Time stamp from UTC to Seoul. I tried to follow the following discussion [Excel - How to convert UTC date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456115/excel-how-to-convert-utc-date-time) but this seems to deal with addressing the T and +03:00 which I have no idea about. My excel sheet has a simple '5/21/2016 5:39:35 AM' which is in UTC. How can I change it to Seoul time? Thanks a million for any help!

Comment: Add `9/24` to it? 1 day equals one, so if you want to add a fraction of a day, well 9 hours is equivalent to 9/24... I think the difference between UTC and Seoul is 9 hours, if Google is right.

Comment: What is your `system date separator`. Is it a `dot` (`.`) or a slash (`/`)?

Comment: @VBasic2008 its a slash - thanks.