# Convert UTC Time/Date to Local Time/Date keeping milliseconds

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
2021-01-14T17:00:23.87Z
```

I am trying to convert the info above to date and time and keep milliseconds. Does anyone have a formula for this?

Comment: give me a second, this has been answered many times on this site.

Comment: see: https://superuser.com/questions/1455511/how-to-convert-utc-to-typical-date-format-in-excel

Comment: here is a close one from this site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456115/excel-how-to-convert-utc-date-time  one would change the `+` to `z` in my formula.

Answer (score 2):

I give up trying to find a perfect match on this site:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),"T"," ")
```

Then format the cell: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.00`

[image]